# Maven Wildfly plugin deploy takes a long time

Tags: maven, wildfly

Is there anything I can do to improve the time of the wildfly deployment using maven? The size of the war is 35mb and each deploy spends almost 5 min to make a deploy, is it normal? When I am developing and I need to do a lot of deploys, it takes too much time. This is in the development environment.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.Final</version>
        <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
         </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Is WildFly running locally on your development computer? 5 minutes seems like a while if everything is running locally.

Comment: Yes, it's. The problem is because when I am working at the front end, all the time I need to do a deploy.

Comment: With the maven plugin it's deployed over a network connection, but that should be fairly fast I'd think on the same machine. Are there a lot of EJB's or CDI beans? Anything that might take some time to process?

Comment: No, there are no EJB and CDI. I don't think so.

Comment: I'm not sure what would be taking that long unless there is some weird network setup.

Comment: What is the breakdown of time? 5 mins from the moment the deploy goal starts to finishes or the full maven build?

Comment: Just the deploy